# How to use the value of a variable to create a cell comment in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, syntax, comments

I am struggling to find the syntax of how to add a comment using the value of a variable, or if it's even supported through VBA.

For example, it's easy enough to know that:

`Range("YourRange").AddComment "Your Text"`

...will add a comment to a range of cells with whatever `"Your text"` is. What I am trying to figure out is how to use a variable's value instead of `"Your Text"`. I have tried various combinations using an `&`, and have yet to find any syntax online.

> **Receiving Error:**
>   `VBA Runtime Error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined error`

```
If sinput = 1 Then
    Num = InputBox("How much did you spend?", "July - " & gasString)
    Range("F11").Value = Range("F11").Value + Num
    Range("F11").AddComment Num
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

Minimal example with a variable:

```
Sub TesetMe()

    Dim text As String
    text = "someText"
    Range("B2").AddComment text

End Sub
```

Comment: Beat me to it !! +1

Comment: @QHarr - and I was even amazed that the `AddComment`  did not work initially.

Comment: @QHarr - you gotta be speedy when Vityata's online...  :-)

Comment: @Vityata would this work the same if text was a double or integer rather than a string?

Comment: @ashleedawg :D.

Comment: @Len - Comments can only be string, so although it would *probably* work with a numeric variable, the "right way" to do it is to convert the number to a string, like `Range("B2").AddComment CStr(myNumericVariable)`.

Comment: @Len - declare it as a string and put an integer or double in it.

Comment: ...or just do what Vityata says.  :)   (psst @Len be sure to check out Vitaya's website, there a link from Vityata's [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5448626/vityata)... there's lots of handy Excel & VBA stuff to explore!)

Comment: @ashleedawg - I guess QHarr is not following :D

Comment: @ashleedawg awesome I got it to work, thanks for the edits as well.

Comment: @Len - glad you got it figured out; in the end that's all that matters...  oh and *Welcome to [so]!*